# Deep learning in Mathematica for model building and prediction

Tags: neural-networks

I have 5 predictor variables and 1 independent variable. Previously I was building neural networks for prediction of the independent variable. Is it possible to implement this in mathematica using deep learning for improved results?

Appreciate any advice on this.

Regards
Ben

Comment: Please add more info.What's variable.Can you provide code?

Comment: Mathematica has heaps of built-in AI functionality: Check out the documentation section about Machine Learning (http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/MachineLearning.html) or specifically the new symbolic neural net framework (http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/NeuralNetworks.html).